# How to duplicate production environment for Sidekiq load testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, sidekiq

At my company we are using Rails + Sidekiq to onboard our users. When they log in for the first time, we feed them through a data pipeline that parses/aggregates their data, as well as make calls to external APIs. When one worker finishes, it queues up the next stage in the pipeline for that user.

I would like to make improvements to our pipeline since (it is prone to blocking/starving in some cases). But rather than roll out to production, I want to create a local environment where I can test arbitrary modifications and use cases - that's what this question is all about. Specifically, I would like to:

- Create a dev environment that approximates production in terms of Sidekiq behavior
- Know the order in which workers are being enqueued will resemble (if not match) production
- Fake/mock calls to external services
- Test arbitrary cases, such as

  - 1, 10, 1000 simultaneous signups, etc
  - low to high variance in response time and reliability of external services
- Quantify worker performance to compare results - time started, time spent, time spent idle/blocking

Based on my searching, right now I am considering using rspec to run my arbitrary test cases, with FactoryGirl to model external requests (both to fake response data and to vary response times). I don't know if this is a good approach. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that rspec and factory_girl are good for load testing.
Their main purpose is unit tests.

If I were you, I'd run another set of servers, completely same as production.
Then you can write some capybara scenarios, that will simulate real user iteraction with system.

Only such approach can guarantee you valuable results of load testing.

If you mock all external api requests, it'll make your app much faster, so you will not learn how long it'll take on real production mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To clarify, I am mostly interested in examining/comparing how jobs get prioritized in sidekiq, as opposed to just performance. For the external requests, actually making the calls is a challenge in our particular case, and possibly not ideal since we want to control as much as possible to focus on analyzing Sidekiq behavior.

Comment: Anyway, you should have running sidekiq instance to make such stress-tests.
So it won't be classical rspec tests. It seems that you need some custom testing framework. Not sure if such tools exist in public.